# How do I make a "ragged" table?

Tags: tables

Here is a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
$n$&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
$f_n$&1&1&2&3&5\\ \hline
$F_n$&0.724&1.171&1.894&3.065&4.960\\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{}\\ \hline
$n$&6&7&8&9\\ \hline
$f_n$&8&13&21&34\\ \hline
$F_n$&8.025&12.985&21.010&33.994\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: two-row table]

I'm just trying to fit 1,2,3,...9 on a page, and it's too wide, so I'm breaking it into two separate rows.  But, the `hline`s on the second row extend out over the empty cell.  How do I write a table without those lines sticking out?

Or is there some better way to fit this table?

**EDIT**:

The following solution isn't terrible, but it doesn't look the greatest since the boxes don't line up between tables.  Or maybe that's good?

```
\[
\begin{array}{l}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
$n$&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
$f_n$&1&1&2&3&5\\ \hline
$F_n$&0.724&1.171&1.894&3.065&4.960\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip
\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
$n$&6&7&8&9\\ \hline
$f_n$&8&13&21&34\\ \hline
$F_n$&8.025&12.985&21.010&33.994\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{array}
\]
```

[image: another table]

Comment: Is there any reason not to flip the rows and the columns?  (Also, most tables look better without lines, especially vertical lines). Check the [tag:booktabs] tag for plenty of examples on the site)

Comment: How much too wide is your table? If it's just a few pt, you could probably make it fit into one line by decreasing the fonts size and/or the value of `\tabcolsep`.

Answer (score 7):

- you need to fill all cells, at least with empty `multicolumn` cells
- second part of table should have `cline{1-5}` instead of `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
$n$     & 1     &2      & 3         & 4     & 5     \\ \hline
$f_n$   & 1     &1      & 2         & 3     & 5     \\ \hline
$F_n$   & 0.724 &1.171  & 1.894     & 3.065 & 4.960 \\ \hline
\mcc[5]{}                                           \\ \cline{1-5}
$n$     & 6     &7      & 8         & 9     & \mcc{}\\ \cline{1-5}
$f_n$   & 8     &13     & 21        & 34    & \mcc{}\\ \cline{1-5}
$F_n$   & 8.025 &12.985 & 21.010    & 33.994& \mcc{}\\ \cline{1-5}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a regular `article` documentclass, here are several different approaches that all make sure the table fits into the available textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.4pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    $n$     & 1     &2      & 3         & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7      & 8       & 9     \\ \hline
    $f_n$   & 1     &1      & 2         & 3     & 5     & 8     & 13     & 21      & 34    \\ \hline
    $F_n$   & 0.724 &1.171  & 1.894     & 3.065 & 4.960 & 8.025 & 12.985 & 21.010  & 33.994\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    $n$     & 1     &2      & 3         & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7      & 8       & 9     \\ \hline
    $f_n$   & 1     &1      & 2         & 3     & 5     & 8     & 13     & 21      & 34    \\ \hline
    $F_n$   & 0.724 &1.171  & 1.894     & 3.065 & 4.960 & 8.025 & 12.985 & 21.010  & 33.994\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|*{5}{wc{2.75em}|}}
    \hline 
    $n$   & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     \\ \hline
    $f_n$ & 1     & 1     & 2     & 3     & 5     \\ \hline
    $F_n$ & 0.724 & 1.171 & 1.894 & 3.065 & 4.960 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \smallskip

  \begin{tabular}{|c|*{4}{wc{2.75em}|}}
    \hline
    $n$   &6     & 7      & 8      & 9      \\ \hline
    $f_n$ &8     & 13     & 21     & 34     \\ \hline
    $F_n$ &8.025 & 12.985 & 21.010 & 33.994 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1]S[table-format=2] S[table-format=2.3]}
    \toprule
    {$n$} &  {$f_n$}  & {$F_n$}  \\
    \midrule 
    1     & 1         & 0.724  \\ 
    2     & 1         & 1.171  \\ 
    3     & 2         & 1.894  \\ 
    4     & 3         & 3.065  \\ 
    5     & 5         & 4.960  \\ 
    6     & 8         & 8.025  \\ 
    7     & 13        & 12.985 \\ 
    8     & 21        & 21.010 \\ 
    9     & 34        & 33.994 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive, thank you! Even though this does not answer the question I asked, it answered what I wanted (to fit the table in the best looking way). This is a book (not article), and it has been set to 6"x9", so I used the `tabcolsep` solution with it set to `3.5pt`.